# Match sequence with exactly x or y or z repetitions?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace hex values of datetime2 in SQL-scripts.

They look like

```
CAST(0x07000000000067B708 AS DateTime2)
```

And according to 
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/12/15/the-internal-storage-of-a-datetime2-value.aspx
the possible lengths are 14 or 16 or 18 hex characters.

Now in my regex I can do {14,18}, which means 14 to 18 repetitions. 
But how can do exactly 14 or exactly 16 or exactly 18 repetitions (not on 15, not on 17) ?

```
    sql = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(sql, @"CAST\s*\(\s*0x[a-f0-9]{14,18}\s*AS\s*datetime2\s*\)"
        , new System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator(ReplaceDateTime2)
    , System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

I've been on 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx
but there's no description of how the syntax is with or, and {14|16|18} doesn't work, and google isn't helpful either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
@"CAST\s*\(\s*0x[a-f0-9]{14}(?:[a-f0-9]{2}){0,2}\s*AS\s*datetime2\s*\)"
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `[a-f0-9]{14}(?:[a-f0-9]{2}){0,2}` will match 14 hex chars and then 0 to 2 occurrences of 2 hex chars will follow.

*Details*:

- `CAST` - literal char sequence `CAST`
- `\s*\(\s*` - a `(` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces on both sides
- `0x` - `0x` substring
- `[a-f0-9]{14}` - 14 hex letters or digits
- `(?:[a-f0-9]{2}){0,2}` - 0 to 2 sequences of 2 hex letters or digits
- `\s*AS\s*` - substring `AS` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `datetime2` - a substring `datetime2`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\)`  - a closing literal `)`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=CAST%5Cs*%5C(%5Cs*0x%5Ba-f0-9%5D%7B14%7D(%3F%3A%5Ba-f0-9%5D%7B2%7D)%7B0%2C2%7D%5Cs*AS%5Cs*datetime2%5Cs*%5C)&i=CAST(0x0700000067B708%20AS%20DateTime2)%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F14%0D%0ACAST(0x070000000067B708%20AS%20DateTime2)%20%20%20%20%2F%2F16%0D%0ACAST(0x07000000000067B708%20AS%20DateTime2)%20%20%2F%2F18%0D%0A%0D%0ACAST(0x0700000000067B708%20AS%20DateTime2)%20%2F%2F17%0D%0ACAST(0x07000000067B708%20AS%20DateTime2)%20%20%20%2F%2F15%0D%0A&o=i)

Answer (score 1):

Simply make 3 possible groupings:

```
((?:[a-f0-9]{12})|(?:[a-f0-9]{14})|(?:[a-f0-9]{16}))
```

Alternatively, capture the shorter and make the longer optional:

```
([a-f0-9]{12}(?:[a-f0-9]{2})?(?:[a-f0-9]{2})?)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternation group:

```
(?:[a-f0-9]{14}|[a-f0-9]{16}|[a-f0-9]{18})
```

Or use @Wiktor's solution which I found a bit harder to read but cleaner if you're familiar with regexes.